# Barttletts test and F test with 3 variables

Tags: statistics, variance, hypothesis-testing

I linked a picture with the assignment.

I know how to do F-tests with 2 variances and means, but with 3, I am out of luck. I could do it if I had a dataset in R. but not manual in R or by hand, as it is in this assignment.

> [image]

Comment: I know its bad with the picture. But I don't know how to set up otherwise, but I will get better next time

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to know whether the three sample variances
.137, .084, and .179 in the table of your Question are
consistent with equal group variances for Groups 1, 2, and 3.

You are correct that you can't do Bartlett's test from the summary statistics you have. The same is true of Levene's test for equal variances (used when data are not normal).

However, Hartley's F-max test can be based on what you have in the table.
It takes the ratio $F_{\text{Max}}$ of the largest of $k$ group variances
divided by smallest. For your data $k = 3$ and the ratio is $.179/.084 = 2.13.$
A [table](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/tables/hartley.pdf) of 5% critical values for $k = 3$ and sample sizes 8 and 9 shows that rejection of the null hypothesis of equal variances would require the ratio to exceed about 6 or 7
in order to reject. (The table assumes all three sample sizes are equal,
so a little 'flexibility' is in order.)

Hartley's test is not used much these days because it is less powerful for
normal data than Bartlett's test, and statistical software assumes complete
data are at hand.

In your case it would be
safe to say there is no significant difference among the three if
there is no significant difference between the smallest and largest of three.
The F-test for two sample variances is easy to do with the values you have.
Minitab output (slightly abridged for relevance) for a one-sided test is shown below. (The P-value for a two-sided test is twice as large.)
It seems your sample variances are nowhere near significantly different.

```
Statistics

Sample  N  StDev  Variance    
First   9  0.423     0.179     
Second  8  0.290     0.084    

Ratio of standard deviations = 1.460
Ratio of variances = 2.131

Test
                       Test
Method  DF1  DF2  Statistic  P-Value
F         8    7       2.13    0.167
```

Answer (score 0):

2) $F$-test, assume $\alpha=0.05$:
$$H_0:\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu_3\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ H_1: \text{at least two differ}\\
\begin{align}F&=\frac{MST}{MSE}\approx \frac{\color{red}{0.90231}}{\color{blue}{0.13531}}\approx 6.67,\\
MST&=\frac{SST}{k-1}=\frac{\sum n_i(\bar{y}_i-\bar{\bar{y}})^2}{k-1}\approx \\
&\approx\frac{9(0.7467-0.77002)^2+\cdots +9(1.0889-0.77002)^2}{2}\approx \color{red}{0.90231},\\
MSE&=\frac{\sum (n_i-1)s_i^2}{n-k}=\frac{(9-1)\cdot 0.13655+\cdots+(9-1)\cdot 0.17854}{26-3}\approx \color{blue}{0.13531},\\
F_{\alpha/2,k-1,n-k}&=F_{0.025,2,23}=4.35,\\
F&>F_{\alpha/2} \Rightarrow \text{Reject $H_0$}.\end{align}$$